# Выбор идеальной IDE для веб-разработки

Tags: ide

Всем, привет! Друзья, интересно мнение и совет любого. Недавно озадачился поиском подходящей IDE для веб-разработки, изучил много материала по этому вопросу и для себя сделал следующий вывод, продолжать использовать Notepad++ не в обиду разработчикам (с убогим интерфейсом от которого воротит) или копить деньги на MAC для использования  [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/). Почему склоняюсь к этим вот редакторам, а потому, что у них есть поддержка работы по FTP. Подскажите пожалуйста, какими редакторами или IDE пользуетесь вы.

Comment: эммм...копить на Mac стоимостью 1500 - 4000 долларов чтобы иметь возможность работать с IDE за 75$? Я правда всё правильно понял??? Плюс критерии выбора IDE у вас мягко говоря крайне странные

Comment: возможно, странный совет, но для вебразработки идеально подходит linux.  Судите сами - apache, php, mysql для локального тестирования прямо "из коробки".  Всяческие ftp клиенты, git/svn - также. Редакторов - пруд пруди. Сама ось - IDE.

А мак - это просто хорошо испорченная freebsd :).

Comment: @KoVadim вот и мне советуют freebsd, но MAC же красиво ) да не на самом деле плюшек очень много у маковской эспресы

Comment: @DreamChild а особых критериев и нету, вы правильно заметили, для веб-разработки нет так уж и важно иметь гигантскую IDE чтобы пользоваться только редактором кода и проводником, все остальное делается с помощью инструментов браузера или я не прав

Comment: Что за странное отношение "МАС эе красиво" :) Вам шашечки или ехать?
Лично я за sublime, по поводу редактировать через фтп -- а нафига? лучше это через VCS делать уж. Хотите сразу заливать отредактиованное на сервер? ну поставьте на сервер [Github-Auto-Deploy](https://github.com/logsol/Github-Auto-Deploy), с GitLab Это тоже работает отлично, так и редактирую файлы на сервере.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не соответствует тематике SO

Answer (score 9):

Здравствуйте. Итак, мое мнение: однозначно emacs. А вообще вот, процитирую ответ на один мой похожий вопрос на хэшкоде:

"Все вот думал, когда же наступит тот момент, когда мне придется сказать в стиле "да я в твои годы!.. и т.д.". И вот... Этот момент, скорее всего, настал. Вам, - как видно из вашего недавнего поста, - 16 лет, и вы позиционируете себя как молодого человека, увлекшегося программированием. То вы собираетесь использовать Go для масштабного веб-проекта, то не можете подобрать цветовую схему для редактора Sublime Text 3, чтобы начать программировать, причем одну тему для дневной работы, а вторую - для ночной. И все это для того, чтобы, как вы в том же посте и выразились, в ближайшее время опять же - начать писать на языке golang. Теперь вот уже и сам IDE стоит под вопросом.

Я в ваши годы, а точнее, с 12 лет и где-то до 16-ти, сидел дома за гудящим компьютером ЕС-1840, оснащенным черно-белым монитором "Электроника". Там, поверьте мне, не было никаких тем - ни ночных, ни дневных. Я не говорю уже о том, что понятие "графика" сводилось к алгоритмам отображения простых геометрических фигур, причем практически, если так можно выразиться, "попиксельно". Не было и никаких навороченных IDE, а пиком эргономичности UI считались Norton/Volkov Commander. Windows и графический интерфейс? Не, не слышали.. Там был MS-DOS во всей его красе.

Но зато, мой юный друг, были Borland TurboPascal, Borland C++, Microsoft GW-BASIC и другие - простейшие в смысле графической оболочки (если понятие таковой вообще там можно было найти), но необходимые среды разработки под MS-DOS, благодаря которым многие стали профессионалами без всяких ночных тем. О да, забыл упомянуть: тогда не было никакого Интернета и ответ на вопрос типа "А как сделать, чтобы..." нельзя было найти с помощью Google. И книг не было. Разве что книга В. Э. Фигурнова "IBM PC для пользователя" - почти что единственная библия нашего поколения и скудные сканы с документаций, поставлявшимися с официальными версиями вышеозначенных программ и считавшимися ценнее золота.

Как я уже вам писал, я знаю людей (да и многие знают), которые годами собираются выучить Java, но никак не могут определиться, что лучше - Eclipse или NetBeans. В результате они остались на месте, не выучив ровным счетом ничего. А все потому что походили к процессу не с той стороны, явно полагая, что корень их непонимания азов программирования связан с использованием неудобного IDE.

Я желаю вам прогресса, а поэтому прошу: не повторяйте опыт неудачников и не наступайте на эти затертые чужие грабли. Учитесь и начинайте программировать, а темы оставьте на потом.

Удачи вам!"
Вот ссыль: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/241471#244548

Comment: Хороший ответ и правильный :)

Comment: @just Да уж, не пробиваемый ответ :) Спасибо!

Comment: @just ну хорошо, среда -- emacs. А какой редактор посоветуете? Гадюку? EDT? или кого?

Comment: vim что ли вбросить:).

Comment: @KoVadim ну если человеку нравится emacs, то viper (гадюка) -- вполне подходящий вариант.

Comment: теперь я знаю ещё одно извращение - vim в emacs:)

Comment: @KoVadim viper -- эмуляция vi, не vim.

Answer (score 8):

PHPStorm - все что нужно в одном флаконе.

Comment: Редактировать файлы напрямую на ftp — это PhpStorm не позволяет. Цитирую разрабаточкиво PhpStorm:
You can't use IDE w/out making a local copy first. There is a principal *technical* restriction. Same goes for all kinds of mapped remote folders. This is strictly unsupported. Please use «File|Create project from remote...» wizard to quickly setup remote project.

Comment: Ну и замечательно! Привычка редактировать все на живую - пагубная. Зато в остальных аспектах - чудный IDE

Comment: да нет, я не командный разработчик, я сам по себе, у меня нету командных проектов, и мне не надо привязывать проект к системе контроля версий, мне просто нужно править код не создавая локальных копий... а так я все прекрасно понимаю, что когда будет командная разработка вот тогда и воспользуюсь другими даже более удобными и бесплатными, и более внешне привлекательными, и простыми средствами чем PHPStorm

Comment: >да нет, я не командный разработчик (...) и мне не надо привязывать проект к системе контроля версий 

@Артёмыч это очень наивное утверждение, если вы пишете что-нибудь  серьезнее Hello World'a

Comment: @DreamChild почитайте комментарии  :) http://habrahabr.ru/post/146563/

Comment: @Артёмыч почитал. Признаться, мастерством написания без использования систем контроля версий от этого чтения не просветлился

Comment: @DreamChild да не, просвещаться не надо было, просто у людей те же вопросы, что и у меня, я прошу подсказать советом по выбору IDE, а не по выбору методики разработки приложений :)

Answer (score 5):

Из редакторов, на мой взгляд, лучший [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

1. Приятный и удобный интерфейс
2. Кроссплатформенный
3. Куча плагинов ( в том числе и SFTP, который для Вас так критичен )
4. Шустрый

Советую его использовать пока не выбрали IDE.

Comment: @Genson да, попробовал, согласен, очень шустрая, я с ней кстати работаю давно, но опять же править код на лету с помощью этого плагина не получиться, все равно придется создать локальную копию файла

Comment: не нужно править "на лету" файлы. это самый надежный способ получить проблемы.

Поредактировали, проверили локально, обновили.

Comment: Поредактировал, сохранил, закрыл, забыл что редактировал :) Как быть? То ли дело когда VCS подсказала, а когда нет такой возможности! В общем поэтому вопрос и поднял, что как бэ нету лучшего кроме как Notepad++ и эспрески для мака :(

Comment: в этом случае на помощь и приходит система контроля версий.

Но для детских проектов вполне подходит rsync (в линуксах/маках - из коробки). Это такой себе copy, но в две стороны. Он получает как параметры локальный каталог и удаленный (может быть и ftp, ssh, и много других вариантов), получает списки файлов, сравнивает их даты и заменяет более старые версии более новыми.

При необходимости, можно забиндить на кнопку/написать скрипт и радоваться жизни.

Comment: как вариант использую связку WinSCP ( с помощью него и профили подключений удобно хранить ) + Sublime. Тогда получается сохранять налету.

Comment: @Сфинкс а как вы связали с WinSCP? Автозагрузка на сервер есть?

Answer (score 2):

Если нужен легковесный красивый редактор, то SublimeText.
Если нужно удобство, автодополнение, переход к объявлению функции по Ctrl-click и прочие фишки, то IDE от JetBrains (Intellij Idea, PHPStorm, WebStorm, PyCharm)

А вообще, vim или emacs и учиться их готовить :)

Comment: Друзья, вы посмотрите с каким удовольствием можно будет работать вот в этих средах http://macrabbit.com/espresso/ и http://www.panic.com/CODA/ только ради приятного интерфейса готов купить MAC, это как работать таксистом на ШОХЕ или любой другой иномарке, ну согласитесь и сравнению поддается не только авто, а все что угодно... и ведь не только интерфейс но всякие фичи которыми напичканы эти тулзы, ведь это наша работа, наши инструменты которыми мы работаем

Comment: У меня был Coda. Да, очень приятный редактор. Но это редактор, но никак не IDE. А сейчас у меня PHPStorm. При работе над сложными и крупными аппликациями это не сравнимо!!!

Comment: @Артёмыч

- Мне почему-то кажется, что вы сильно переоцениваете важность IDE для разработки. Да, инструменты важны, но они никогда не заменят умения абстрактно мыслить, внимания к деталям или, например, владения 10-пальцевым методом печати. Это же, естественно, верно и для вашего примера с автомобилями — навык вождения совершенно ортогонален тому, ездишь ты на "ШОХЕ" или же на иномарке.

- Вместо траты времени на выбор IDE, просто выберите \*любую\*, начните работать, а освободившееся время потратьте на освоение VCS. А то получится как у @just [с его выбором цветовой схемы.](goo.gl/6ewiqM)

Comment: @zhenyab ой да не скажите... Coda 2 - почитайте на сайте набор возможностей ))) далеко уже не просто редактор кода... вот здесь прям на главной http://www.panic.com/coda/

Comment: Да @Артёмыч, я говорю за Coda 2. Если Вы работаете над серьезными проектами с инклюдами, классами и пр., этого редактора НЕ достаточно. Если просто для верстки сайтов - отличный редактор, даже спорить не буду.

Comment: @DreamChild еще раз повторюсь, это абсолютно не ваше дело как я подхожу к работе :) Я просил совет, его я от вас лично так и не получил, пока от вас лично я вижу, что у меня только наср...но в комментариях, увы но это факт!

Comment: @DreamChild нет, кирпичами ср...ть я не стану :) выражайте свои мысли как хотите, если для вас это единственное место, чтобы, хоть как-то самоутвердиться по жизни, ну и вот еще, как специалист в области программирования вы прекрасно знаете, каким трудом получаются знания и поэтому бить по самолюбию негоже, единственное, что я теперь почерпнул от ваших речей, на этом огромное спасибо, что и ваши доводы меня убедили не тратить времени впустую, а расставить правильный приоритет перед выбором той самой идеальной IDE, с момента поднятия темы уже успел подружиться с PHPStrom :) благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim), очень понравились слова "Сама ось - IDE" (относительно GNU/Linux). Очень верные, по-моему, слова.

Насчет "идеальной" IDE что посоветовать даже не знаю, разве что не тратить впустую время. А по поводу функциональной и продуманной, на мой взгляд, для Web-разработки могу высказаться за **PHPStorm**. Мне кажется (и это я наблюдал на опыте коллег), что тем, кому надо работать и этой работы много, эта IDE предоставляет богатые возможности и таким образом является вполне подходящей.

Касательно среды разработки, то не вижу никаких проблем в использовании чего-либо отличного от MAC-ов.

Comment: @y0uix Понял, спасибо, дельный совет, особенно на счет потраченного времени впустую :) Буду вникать в PHPStorm, раз уж все его так дико хвалят )

Answer (score 0):

Пользуюсь Webstorm, но тут нужно учитывать что в основном я пишу javascript логику+css/html. Но если вы копаетесь в php то думаю можно допилить IDE до соотв поддержки (вообще, для php отдельная IDE - PHPstorm). Касаемо notepad++ - идеален для быстрых правок, быстрый, поддерживает Emmet, но нет толков автодополнения что расстраивает. Касаемо дизайна - не знаю, многие ide уродливы и этот редактор не хуже многих. Я лично спасаюсь стилизацией кода.

Comment: PHPStrom, так же как и PyCharm, как собственно и остальные IDE семейства JetBrains поддерживают замечательно Javascript, CSS и HTML.

Comment: Совсем недавно взялся за прочтение [книги][1], так вот там автор говорит, что программирование это творчество, поэтому и творить хочется с удовольствием :)
[1]: http://vmg.pp.ua/books/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%98%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%202.0.pdf